# Take average of window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe, I want to average first 12 rows, then next 12 rows and so on. I wrote a for loop for this task

```
df_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(df),12):
    print(i,i+12)
    df_list.append(df.iloc[i:i+12].mean())
pd.concat(df_list,1).T
```

Is there an efficient way to do this without for loop

Comment: check `.rolling(12).mean()` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: no, its not serving my purpose. let say i have 120 rows , took mean of 0:12 and 12:24 and so on. after the operation i only left with 10 rows. but rolling mean giving me same rows as  total number of rows in data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the index by N i.e. 12 in your case, then group the dataframe by the quotient, and finally call `mean` on these groups:

```py
# Random dataframe of shape 120,4
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,100,(120,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df.groupby(df.index//12).mean()

           A          B          C          D
0  49.416667  52.583333  63.833333  47.833333
1  60.166667  61.666667  53.750000  34.583333
2  49.916667  54.500000  50.583333  64.750000
3  51.333333  51.333333  56.333333  60.916667
4  51.250000  51.166667  50.750000  50.333333
5  56.333333  50.916667  51.416667  59.750000
6  53.750000  57.000000  45.916667  59.250000
7  48.583333  59.750000  49.250000  50.750000
8  53.750000  48.750000  51.583333  68.000000
9  54.916667  48.916667  57.833333  43.333333
```

Comment: As a side note, this method will not work properly if there are duplicate indexes

Comment: @NuriTaş I understand that, but `reset_index` method is there for rescue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to split your dataframe to seperate chunks with 12 rows. Then you can use `np.arange` inside groupby to take the mean of each seperate chunk:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 12).mean()
```